# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.FeatureManagement.IFeatureManager' while attempting to activate 'Startup'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, feature-flags

I have asp.net core 3.1 web api project. I have added the nuget package: Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore

Add the below in the appsettings.local.json:

```
{
"FeatureManagement": {
    "EnableNewFeature": true
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;
        private readonly IFeatureManager featureManager;
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, IFeatureManager featureManager)
        {
            this.configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
            this.webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(webHostEnvironment));
            this.featureManager = featureManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(featureManager));
        }
    
        public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
       /// Code.Start
       services.AddFeatureManagement();

       /// Code.End
      }
        public async Task Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, L10NCacheInitializationService l10nIniService)
        {
            app.UseIf(await featureManager.IsEnabledAsync(AppKeys.EnableNewFeature), x => x.UseNewFeature());
        }
    }
```

On validation I came across the below error :
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.FeatureManagement.IFeatureManager' while attempting to activate 'Startup'.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you followed [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core?tabs=core5x) for setting this up because your code looks nothing like what's in that tutorial

Comment: Your edit has introduced what you might call a "chicken and egg" situation - you cant use feature management (in the constructor) before it's added to your DI container (using `AddFeatureManagement`) - please read the tutorial I linked above

Comment: Thanks @Jamiec for your response. I got the problem now. But is there any other way how the feature flag can be used within the Configure method in Startup.cs

Comment: Sure there is, see answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot inject `IFeatureManager` in to the constructor of `Startup` because it's not yet registered. Once registered you can get it using `app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService`

With `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` at the top of your file it would look something like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
        this.webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(webHostEnvironment));
    }
    
    public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
    {
       services.AddFeatureManagement();
    }
    public async Task Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, L10NCacheInitializationService l10nIniService)
    {
        var featureManager = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IFeatureManager>();
        app.UseIf(await featureManager.IsEnabledAsync(AppKeys.EnableNewFeature), x => x.UseNewFeature());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jamiec for your response. It helped me to fix the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use `IFeatureManager` in the `Startup` class for other cases like using inside of the `ConfigureServices` method, you can use this extension method:

```
public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static bool IsFeatureEnabled(this IConfiguration configuration, string feature)
    {
        var featureServices = new ServiceCollection();
        featureServices.AddFeatureManagement(configuration);
        using var provider = featureServices.BuildServiceProvider();
        var manager = provider.GetRequiredService<IFeatureManager>();

        return manager.IsEnabledAsync(feature).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```